# MSFT SQL Server 2016 Version - What is the Difference between RTM and Standard

Tags: sql-server

A recent issue that occurred was identified by software engineering to be a result of installing SQL Server RTM instead of SQL Server Standard. I have done the obligatory google search to attempt to find a difference between release versions but may not know enough to know what I do not know about Microsoft SQL Server versioning. Is there anyone who has an official reference to Microsoft documentation that can explain the difference between an RTM version of MSFT SQL Server 2016 vs MSFT SQL Server 2016 standard?

Comment: If `select @@version` displays RTM...Standard Edition...,you might need to update your instance as there are two SPacks available and a few CUs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177312/sql-server-2016-build-versions

Comment: Let's see if this comment is deleted. I do not disagree with the downvotes or the suggestions, but to date, no one has provided any official Microsoft documentation that demonstrates something that is already known.

Comment: @Bill...please don't feel disheartened by the downvotes. It is very easy to skim through a question and simply click on a down-arrow. It is way harder to spend time trying to understand the question and the "why"/reasoning behind it. The majority of people are here to help, just stay positive and there is already a valid answer by marc_s, which clears the misunderstanding of the engineering department of yours. If you scroll down this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185 .. to Method 4:

Comment: .. run the following query: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`  you will see that RTM refers to the productlevel while Enterprise/Standard/Developer refer to editions. Just use this same query on your instance and show the engineering department that Standard edition is already installed. If the product level is still RTM then this means that your instance has never been "patched" updated, with service packs and cumulative updates.

Comment: @lptr Thank you. If it wasn't against the rules I would send you an AMZN gift card. The downvotes do not bother me, I agree with the downvotes. I do not even like the fact that I have to ask this question. However, again today there was a statement from engineering saying that the product was only approved for standard and RTM was installed. I am not a SQL DBA. I do know that the information presented here is accurate and it is appreciated by me.I apologize to the SO community for asking such a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Standard** is one of the **editions** of SQL Server, with others being

- Express (including Express LocalDB, Express with Advanced Services)
- Web
- Enterprise
- Developer
  etc.

**RTM** denotes the first/initial *release-to-manufacturing* release - a full, finished release (not a beta, not a release candidate - a full finished product).  It is also the initial finished release - without any "service packs" or "cumulative updates" yet.

Those are two **totally unrelated** things ... you cannot get a *difference* between the two, since they denote two utterly unrelated facts about SQL Server